# Can an Investigator use a skill token when attempting a luck check?

Tags: mansions-of-madness

Skill tokens allow you to add your luck to the attribute you are testing. In the case where you need to check your luck, can you use a skill token to effectively double your attribute score?

e.g. a luck value of 3 becomes 6 after using a skill token because you are adding your luck to your luck.

Comment: any reason for the down vote? I know the question seems simple,  but it's an oversight that can happen quite easily in game

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The manual page 13 says:
"A player may never spend a skill point to add his Luck to his Luck."
So no that is not allowed.